# CodenameOne IOS build failing... Unknown image type 0

Tags: codenameone

My app is compiling for Android but not for IOs

```
iOS Build Error Thu Dec 20 2018 21:46:07 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
Android Successful build - 'AppCliente' Took - 0:58 At - 21:47 Dec 20th 2018
iOS Build Error Thu Dec 20 2018 21:49:24 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

It seems that I have an offending Image of some sort

```
Process return code is 0
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown image type 0
java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:501)
com.codename1.build.daemon.Executor.getScaledInstance(Executor.java:1630)
com.codename1.build.daemon.Executor.createIconFile(Executor.java:934)
com.codename1.build.daemon.IPhoneBuilder.generateIcons(IPhoneBuilder.java:3957)
com.codename1.build.daemon.IPhoneBuilder.build(IPhoneBuilder.java:1246)
com.codename1.build.daemon.Executor$5.run(Executor.java:847)
```

How can I find out which is the source of the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You replaced the icon with an image file that isn't a standard 512x512 PNG file.

Comment: It is a 512x512 16bit png file.

Comment: If you replace it with the default icon just to test, does it pass? What do you mean by 16 bit? Per channel? I'm not sure if we support that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was having transparency bit enabled in the icon. I set up a full background (and switched the icon to 32 bit) and it worked.